# web component test not running, command line gives error, wct is not a command

Tags: javascript, web-component-tester, wct

I just install web-component-tester by npm and trying to run test by wct command, but getting error.

WCT command is not working cmd is not recognizing this command

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <script src="../node_modules/web-component-tester/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="../button/solid-button.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<solid-button></solid-button>
<script>
    suite('<solid-button>', function () {
        let component = document.querySelector('solid-button');
        test('renders button', () => {
            assert.isOk(component.shadowRoot.querySelector('button'));
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

```js
const button= document.createElement("button");
button.innerText="solid button";

class SolidButton extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(button);

    }
    connectedCallback(){}
}
window.customElements.define('solid-button', SolidButton);
```

'wct' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Are you install web-component-tester or web-component-test